# Access to file names in internal storage of mobile

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I want to build a file explorer app. I can list file names in SD card (External Storage) but how to access file names in internal storage of mobile?

Comment: [External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), as the term is used in the Android SDK, is rarely an SD card. You have no access to what the Android SDK calls [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), except the tiny corner that is your own app's files.

Comment: u are saying the files which I will store in internal storage through the app can only be accessed

Comment: I want to list all files and folders present in phone

Comment: You do not have access to "all files and folders present in phone", except perhaps on a rooted device.

Comment: apart from data @ sdcard/emulated/0 did i have access to other data like in root directory or I dont know in phone memory.Sorry for repetitive questions

Answer (score 1):

You can get internal storage with try this method: `getFilesDir()`. So path of your file is: `getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName`